# XCode Instruments can't open .trace file: The file couldn't be opened because there is not such file

Tags: xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

I shared .trace file that I created with XCode 12.5 Instruments and sent it to the other developers to analyze but they can not open it because of next error:

[image: The file couldn't be opened because there is not such file]

I don't have this file on my mac and don't know how to find it but I can open my file successfully.

How to share a .trace file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find `0B463CA7-E796-4DB1-B46B-EEBE0B1664E7` file from inside your .trace file.

1. Open `your_file.trace` (i.e. 'Show Package Contents' in Finder)
2. Unzip `your_file.trace/shared_data/1.run/0B463CA7-E796-4DB1-B46B-EEBE0B1664E7.zip`
3. Then you can find the second `your_file.trace` in the unzipped folder e.g.: `Users/user/Downloads/your_file.trace`
4. Open the second .trace file and find `0B463CA7-E796-4DB1-B46B-EEBE0B1664E7` e.g: `your_file.trace/shared_data/1.run/0B463CA7-E796-4DB1-B46B-EEBE0B1664E7`
5. Copy `0B463CA7-E796-4DB1-B46B-EEBE0B1664E7` file to `your_file.trace/shared_data/1.run` of your root .trace file.

As a result you must have both `0B463CA7-E796-4DB1-B46B-EEBE0B1664E7` and `0B463CA7-E796-4DB1-B46B-EEBE0B1664E7.zip` at the same location inside your .trace file and now it is available to open anywhere.

If you open this file on your mac steps to unzip and find this file are made automatically by Instruments because the zip file have a folder structure that points to your user but this doesn't work for an other user so may be it's a bug of Instruments.